# Can't run Python 2.7 from powershell [Windows 10]

Tags: python, powershell

What I have tried/done so far -

- I used the "Windowsx86-64 MSI Installer (2.7.0) from [this link](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/)
- Added environment variables by going to system properties and clicking "Environment Variables..." button. Then I click on the "Path" variable under user variables and click "edit". I then add in the path "C:/Python27" which I can confirm is where python.exe is located.

**I've also tried setting the path using these commands**

- $env:path="$env:Path;C:\Python27"
- [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27", "User")
- [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", $Env:Path + ";C:\Python27", "Machine")

I don't really know what those commands do, but I found them in other SO threads.
I've restarted powershell, I've ran it as admin. I restarted my PC. And I am out of ideas.

**EDIT** - I get Python 2 is no longer supported. If I could use a newer version I would, but I can't. Still, there is no reason powershell shouldn't be able to work with python scripts.

**EDIT2**

```
PS C:\windows\system32> (Get-Command python).Source
C:\Users\BestInTOWN\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
PS C:\windows\system32> [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 
'User') C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\BestInTOWN\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\BestInTOWN\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Python27;
```

**Edit3/Answer**
Went to settings and searched for "Manage App Execution Aliases". Then proceeded to turn off App Installer for python.exe and python3.exe.

Comment: Don't even bother. Use a newer version of Python. Also, blindly running commands without understanding what they do (even if they are found on SO) is very dangerous

Comment: Python 2 [is toast](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/#:~:text=We%20have%20decided%20that%20January,as%20soon%20as%20you%20can.).

Comment: What does the problem look like? What output do you receive when running python 2.7 from PowerShell? How do you run it? I don't see this kind of information in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already put this in the post but I'll add an official answer response as well.

So I went to settings and searched for "Manage App Execution Aliases". Then proceeded to turn off App Installer for python.exe and python3.exe.

Now Python 2.7 shows up when I type python --version in the powershell. And Python scripts work when I run them from powershell

Comment: The problem was, that in your `PATH`, `C:\Users\BestInTOWN\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` came before `C:\Python27`. `C:\Users\BestInTOWN\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` is provided by windows to help to install python (it contains an executable that is called `python.exe`, which is actually not Python).

Comment: That's interesting, thanks for teaching me that (: